# Is it possible to apply outer on A and B which are both matrices, and a function which takes 2 vectors and returns a scalar?

Tags: r

I wish I could use something like:

```
 outer(A,B,myfun)
```

to achieve something like:

```
a<-matrix(nrow=nrow(A),ncol=nrow(B))
for(i in 1:nrow(A))
    for (j in 1:nrow(B))
    {
        a[i,j]<-myfun(A[i,],B[j,])
    }
```

Is there any better way?

Comment: I think you're looking for "inner product" or "inner sum" (if I may) instead of `outer`. `outer` doesn't give you a dimension lesser than your input.

Comment: That's a pretty compact, straightforward way to go. Since `myfun` appears to do clever things with two vectors not necessarily of the same length, I don't think you'll find any tricks to reduce the processing time. Possibly using `Vectorize` on your inner loop would help a bit.   Now Dirk or Gabor will prove me wrong :-)

Answer (score 1):

Cannot give a general answer since details of how `myfun` may affect the answer.

```
ares <- expand.grid(1:nrow(A), 1:nrow(B))
ares$res <- myfun(A[ares[,1], ), B[res[,2] ) 
# but may need mapply("myfun", A[ares[,1], ), B[res[,2] ) on which Vectorize is based
# or do.call(my.fun, ....)
a <- matrix(ares$res, nrow(A), nrow(B) )
```